# List index out of range? Python

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm having trouble with my coding homework, I'm trying to make a GPA calculator and I think that it is complete for the most part, but it won't work because it keeps telling me that there list index out of range in line 8.

```
def main():
    file_name = input("Enter filename:  ")
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    total = [0, 0]
    count = [0, 0]
    for line in file:
        sline = line[:-1].split(" ")
        grade = sline[1]  # Here
        units = sline[2]
        grade_points = (ord("E") - ord(grade))
        print(grade, units, grade_points)
    total = units * grade_points
    gpa = total / units
    print(total)

main()
```

Comment: `sline` has less than 2 elements, e.g. because there's less than 2 fields in the line.

Comment: post a sample of your input file so that people can help you

Answer (score 1):

In line 8, where it says `sline[2]`, the index is the # 2. Apparently sometimes the split you perform, doesn't produce a 3rd index (remember, index's begin on 0, not 1). So when the split doesn't have a 3rd index, but you're asking for it without checking if it exists, then the index is out of range. That's why you're getting that error.