# How to calculate GPA assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a programming assignment that opens a file and calculates the over all GPA.

wherein A= 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, E = 0
the .txt file contains:

ECS10 A 4

ECS20 B 3

JPN4 C 5

PHY9A D 5

the last element is the amount of credits and the letters before that are the grades. I was only able to get the last element and the letters but Im stuck. I keep using if statements in the for loop to get numbers out of the letters but I cant seem to make it work. (im very new at programming so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated) Thanks!

here's what I've got so far:

f = open("grade_file.txt", "r")

line = f.readlines()

#### isolates the numbers

for i in (line):

```
i = i.strip()

print(i[-1:])
```

#### isolates the letters

print("\n")

for i in (line):

```
i = i.strip()

print(i[-3:-2])
```

GPA could be calculated by multiplying the amount of credits to the grade received and divided it by the total number of credits.

Comment: Also, help your friend ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350683/list-index-out-of-range-python

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3-32

grade_mapping = {'A':4, 'B':3, 'C':2, 'D':1, 'E':0}
weighted_sum = 0
credits = 0

for line in open("grade_file.txt", "r"):
    elems = line.split(' ')
    weighted_sum += grade_mapping[elems[1]] * int(elems[2])
    credits += float(elems[2])

gpa = weighted_sum / credits
print(gpa)
```

I used this file to test:

```
ECS10 A 4
ECS20 B 3
JPN4 C 5
PHY9A D 5
```

The result should be `2.35294117647`

Comment: `for line in f` is better

Comment: it said Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Francis/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    weighted_sum += grade_mapping[elems[1]] * int(elems[2])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: what does the += mean? (sorry im really new to programming)

Comment: `a+=b` means `a=a+b`  @FrancisBautista

Comment: You may delete all the blank lines in your grade_file.txt  @FrancisBautista

Comment: thanks for the help @Kun Hu!! How do I get on your level?!?!?! it seems really easy for you guys. ha

Comment: Try the "A Byte of Python" ;-) @FrancisBautista